# What is the difference between document.querySelector and document.body.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

When I log document.body.querySelector('input') and document.querySelector('input') on the console I get the same object. How is this possible? If they are the same (they are in fact the same, I compared them with === operator and it returns true) 
then what role is "body" playing between?

What is the difference between document.body.querySelector & document.querySelector?

Answer (score 1):

With document.body.querySelector you get elements contained within the 'body' tag, while document.querySelector returns element from the entire document

Comment: That's true, might have been good to also provide an example where that matters (e.g querySelectot('body') or querySelector('title') or querySelector('html') etc.).

Comment: They how do they return same object?

Comment: document.body is inside the document. If the selector refers to an element located within the document body they'll both return that element. If not, document.querySelector will execute and document.body.querySelector will not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
        <p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 

        <p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example".</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
          //document.body.querySelector('title').text = "title changed"; //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of null
          document.querySelector('title').text = "title changed"; // work fine
          // document.body trageting only those elements which are inside body tag. 
        }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: the commented parts describing about document.body